# Avoiding repeat binding in Jquery, when binding from inside iFrame to parent

Tags: jquery

I have a tricky scenario - any help would be appreciated.

I have a parent page with a child page inside an iframe. Here is example html:

For the parent page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="banana">Banana</a>

        <iframe src="ChildPage.html" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And then for ChildPage.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
           $('#banana', top.document).click(function() {
              alert('hello world');
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Observe what happens when the submit button is clicked - the click handler is bound twice to the Banana link and two alert dialogs appear.

In this case, the usual technique of preventing multiple bindings doesn't work:

```
// This doesn't work either
var clickHandler = function() {
    alert('hello world');
};

$('#banana', top.document).unbind(clickHandler).bind(clickHandler);
```

That's because when we submit the iframe, clickHandler is treated as a new object, different from the previous clickHandler.

Interestingly, namespaces also don't work - the namespace context seems to be within the window that created the namespace, rather than being tied to the element that it is bound to.

```
// This still doesn't work either
$('#banana', top.document)
    .unbind('click.myns')
    .bind('click.myns', function() {
        alert('hello world');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to the element you are trying to bind your event to, and then doing a check for that property on the event bind.

```
$("#banana:not(.initialized)", top.document).bind();
```

I usually do this when messing around with dynamically created content, like modals and iframe's to conserve state, and to avoid the dreaded double-binding mess.

Comment: I ended up having to use attr(). I was hoping to use data() but that didn't work either - I think because, according to the jquery docs, the data set using data() is cleared when the user 'leaves the page'.